# connected Hopf algebra of infinite Gelfand-Kirillov dimension but of finite dimensional primitive space

Tags: hopf-algebras

I would like to know some examples of connected Hopf algebras which has infinite Gelfand-Kirillov dimension but with primitive space finite dimensional. Any commments are welcome!

Comment: I do not know a concrete example but a (somewhat more refined) version of your question is listed as an open problem (see: question 4.5.3, p. 59) in the following Phd thesis: 
http://dc.uwm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2733&context=etd

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suggest you ping user @Paul Gilmartin on this question. He has various interesting  works on connected HAs and maybe (?) he has something more to say on this.